# Batch update Primary Address

Tags: addresses

I made the mistake of importing work addresses before home addresses. 
How can I update home addresses to all be primary?

Comment: Are you using Drupal with CiviCRM?

Answer (score 1):

The only option i feel is running a query that will switch the primary address from work to home for a set of contacts in a group.

1. Add imported address contact in a group X.
2. Update is_primary to NULL for all address for contacts in a group X.
3. Update is_primary to TRUE for home address for contacts in a group X.

HTH

Pradeep